# where can I ask questions about sharepoint programming?

Tags: support

I've posted to stackoverflow and the response has not been as successful as it normally is.

Answer (score 2):

[There is a Stack Exchange site now for SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). It's in beta, but you might have better luck there.

Comment: No more in beta (yes we are 2 years after), then increase the importance of your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [new Sharepoint Stackexchange beta site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)